How should I determine cable ampacity with the various temperature specs?
I have read conflicting opinions on the ampacity rating for NM-B cable. Please help clarify the code.
Chart 310.16 does not list NM-B cable and 334.80 says The ampacity of Types NM and NMC cable shall be determined in accordance with 310.14, which also does not list nm-b cable.
334.80 also states the ampacity shall not exceed that of a 60°C (140°F) rated conductor. The 90°C (194°F) rating shall be permitted to be used for ampacity adjustment and correction calculations, provided the final calculated ampacity does not exceed that of a 60°C (140°F) rated conductor.
Does this mean that I can use a breaker sized for the 75 degree column if my total continuous ampacity will not be larger than the ampacity in the 60 degree column?
Example - #6 gauge wire is limited to 55 amps in the 60 degree column and 65 amps in the 75 degree column. Based on 334.80 can I use a 60 amp breaker with #6 NM-B cable if the total ampacity will not exceed 55 amps or do I need to use #4 NM-B?

You're conflating a bunch of different things. Basically there are 60 C and 75 C columns. Different wire and cable types fall in one or the other for most purposes. NM-B, a.k.a. Romex, is 60 C. Period.
Checking an ampacity chart, you get:

8 AWG = 40A
6 AWG = 55A
4 AWG = 70A

You don't get to use more. Pretty much "ever" (there may be some exceptions that I'm not aware of). Where "using the higher temperature columns" comes in is for a bunch of ancillary (but sometimes critical) calculations that can limit the allowed current-carrying capacity. But they don't let you increase the capacity.
On top of all of that, no matter what wire, cable, temperature rating, etc. there is a derate for continuous usage. Which basically says that if something can run for a long time then you only get to use 80% of the capacity. For 6 AWG NM-B, that means you can use 55A for short-term but only 55A x 0.8 = 44A continuous. If you have a device that uses extra power at startup but less continuously then that works out great. If it is a resistance heater or EV service equipment that uses the same amount all the time then yes, you "lose" capacity. But that's the way the rules are written.
There is a separate rule about breaker sizing. Normally the breaker should be matched to the maximum capacity of the wire. However, you can oversize the wire (e.g., due to voltage drop concerns on a long run or because you have 12 AWG on hand and only a 15A breaker and your loads are fine on a 15A circuit).
You can also oversize the breaker in one very specific circumstance: The manufacturer doesn't make a breaker that matches the wire/cable capacity. A typical example is Eaton CH. According to the catalog, they make breakers in these sizes:

10A, 15A, 20A, 25A, 30A, 35A, 40A, 45A, 50A, 60A, 70A, 80A, 90A, 100A, 110A, 125A

Which means that for 55A (6 AWG copper, 60 C), 65A (6 AWG copper, 75 C or 4 AWG aluminum, 75 C) and some other sizes you get to use the closest available larger breaker size. But a 6 AWG copper 60 C circuit is still limited to 55A even though it has a 60A breaker - i.e., you can't provision a 60A circuit/48A continuous EVSE on 6 AWG NM-B.

Only added 30A to the list.

You're overoptimistically reading that 90C stuff because you don't know what it's for.   Let me explain what it's for.
Suppose you have four #8 copper circuits inside a conduit, so 8 conductors that matter.  310.12 says we must do an ampacity adjustment, 6-9 conductors adjusts to 70% of the cable ampacity.  For this adjustment, you use the maximum ampacity of the cable. Let's say it is THW cable which is a 75C max cable where #8 is 50a.  So we apply our 70% to 50A giving 35A. But we are landing this #8 on a 60C rated socket, so we are still limited to 40A. The lower of the two numbers prevails.  We don't need to base our conduit thermal adjustment off the socket's 60C restriction because the socket is not inside the conduit.
Or, let's say the cable is crossing an attic which maxes out at 158F (70C). We have to do a thermal adjustment to reflect diminished capacity due to inability to cool.
So... what 334.80 is saying that, for those adjustments only, you use a starting point of the 90C thermal figure. So if we're running through 334.80 on that "4 cables in conduit" exercise with 70% adjustment, for #6 NM we are adjusting off the 90C figure, 75A.  X 70% gives us 52.5 amps.  But if this calculation comes out above the 60C rating, you must still use the lower 60C rating.
Because of this complexity, NM can't simply be listed in the top row of Table 310.16, and that's why 334.80 exists. Contrast with UF cable which does not enjoy that benefit - its adjustments come off its 60C value, so four #6 UF's in a pipe adjust down to 38.5A - OUCH!
So there is no way to exceed the nominal 60C rating of #6 NM, being 55A.  This also means that loads designated as "continuous" e.g. EV charging cannot be more than 44A. Given the extensive pattern of fire we see, I strongly advise to not run EV circuits anywhere near their thermal limits. Even that is gross overkill for home charging,  as Technology Connections discusses here.
Now, what do we do about circuit breakers?  If you can get a 55A breaker, fantastic, but it's not a standard size.  Because of that, availability cannot be assured, and so NEC 240.4(B) allows you to step up to the next standard size.  This does not make it a 60 amp circuit. It still must be treated as a 55A circuit in all respects.

Remember that 60, 75, and 90 degrees are not temperatures of anything you can measure.  They are just labels for 3 different kinds of wire insulation.  If you just think of them as A, B, and C, and use the appropriate column for the wire you bought, the rest of this is easier to understand.
NM-B behaves like 60-degree wire for its own resistive heating, and like 90-degree wire for heating by its environment.  You make those two calculations separately then use the lower number for sizing the breaker and 80% of the lower number for planning continuous loads.
An approximate rule of thumb is that up to 140°F, NM-B will use the standard 60-degree rating, and above that the temperature-adjusted rating for 90-degree wire.   Don't use that, use the tables! But this should give you a feeling for how the rules combine.
